# Aframe how to get intersected elements from raycaster-intersection event

Tags: three.js, aframe, raycasting

I have a raycaster-intersection event listener attached to my right laser controller like so:

```
<a-entity id="rightController" laser-controls="hand: right" raycaster="objects: .collidable; far: 20"></a-entity>

...

rightController.addEventListener("raycaster-intersection", function(e) {
   console.log(e);
});
```

Collidable object example:

`<a-sphere class="collidable" color="yellow" radius="5" position="31.617 7.159 -10.258" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"></a-sphere>`

When the raycaster intersects with a .collidable object the event is successfully emitted but I can't find any information on the intersected object from the event variable (e). I really don't want to have to attach events to each of these objects because I'd have like 20 event listeners.

Console output:
[image]

It's like the event output is incomplete...Aframe docs imply the 'els' array should contain what I'm looking for but it's empty. There's also no .getIntersection() function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

#### Using the A-Frame 1.2.0

The event you want to listen to is: **raycaster-intersected**

then you can get the intersection data from: **evt.detail.el.components.raycaster** that also has the **getIntersection(el)** method

Example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
    init: function () {
      this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', evt => {
        this.raycaster = evt.detail.el;
      });
      this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected-cleared', evt => {
        this.raycaster = null;
      });
    },
    tick: function () {
        if (!this.raycaster) { return; }  // Not intersecting.
        let intersection = this.raycaster.components.raycaster.getIntersection(this.el);
        if (!intersection) { return; } // Not intersecting
        // intersecting
        console.log(intersection);
    }
  });
  </script>
  <a-scene id="scene">
    <a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: .cursor-listener"></a-entity>
    
    <a-plane
        position="0 1.6 -1"
        height="2"
        width="1.5"
        color="red"
        class="cursor-listener"
        cursor-listener
        id="element"
      ></a-plane>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```